# Filter and debounce an observable using values from another observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have 2 observables :

- a source : emits an event each time a change is made in a form
- a "inspector" : emits an event to tell if the change can be saved or not

What I'm trying to do is :

- the source emits values
- debounce values for a minute
- if the controller didn't emit "false" during that time then emit latest value from source

I have seen some similar problems resolved with `withLatestFrom(inspector).filter(...)` but it does not work for me as I need all values emitted from the inspector observable during the debounce time.

I also tried a 'merge' operator but I only care about the source : if the inspector emits values but the source doesn't, the observable i'm trying to build shouldn't either.

Is there a way to achieve this using only observables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is helpful to break this problem down.  I don't quite understand what you're asking for, so here's my best impression:

- Source emits a value.
- After that initial emission we start listening to the inspector for true values.
- Once the debounce time is passed we emit a value if the inspector only emitted true.

The first observation I'd like to make (pardon the pun), is that you don't have to use **debounceTime** to have a debounce-like effect.  I find that **switchMap** with a **timer** on the inside can produce the same results:  **SwitchMap** will cancel previous emissions like **debounce**, and the **timer** can act to delay the emission.

My proposal is that you use **switchMap** from your source and then create an observable from the combination of a **timer** and your inspector.  Use a **filter**  operator so you only emit from the source if the inspector's last emitted result duration the duration of the timer was *true*.

```
this.source.pipe(
  switchMap(x => // switchMap will cancel any emissions if the timer hasn't emitted yet.
    // this combineLatest will only emit once - when the timer emits.
    combineLatest([
        timer(60000), 
        this.inspector.pipe(filter(x => !x), startWith(true))
    ]).pipe( 
      filter(([_, shouldEmit]) => shouldEmit), 
      mapTo(x) // emit source's value
    )
  )
)
```

- Note: **startWith** is used in the inspector's pipe so that at least one result is emitted.  This guarantees that there will be a single emission once **timer** emits.  The filter is on the inspector since all you care about is if a false result prevents emission.
- If you don't want to force the user to wait a minute, you could just use **race** instead of **combineLatest**.  It will emit the result from the first observable that emits.  So you can have the timer emit true after a minute, and the inspector emit any false result.

```
switchMap(x =>
  race(
    timer(6000).pipe(mapTo(true)), // emit true after a minute.
    this.inspector.pipe(filter(x => !x)) // only emit false
  ).pipe(
    take(1), // this might not be necessary.
    filter((shouldEmit) => shouldEmit), 
    mapTo(x) // emit source's value
  )
)
```

Comment: You say: **if the inspector only emitted true.** - but your solution is "every time the inspector emits true". Your solution starts with the inspector emitting false, so it "only emitting true" can't happen anyways. Also, why do you use `startWith` on a value that you immediately filter? Also, you filter the inspector twice? Both times the filter is the same...

Comment: Thanks @MrkSef, the first filter was redundant.  I use startWith so the combineLatest will always emit.  One the timer emits the current value of inspector is checked, that is why that filter is checked.  I changed the language to be more specific.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer ! If I understand the solution correctly, it doesn't quite meet my need. Sorry the description wasn't clear. The inspector or blocker observable emits boolean values. I'm trying to build an observable that listen to the source observable, waits 1 minute, then, if the blocker observable didn't emit false during that time, emits latest value from source. With this solution, if the blocker emits false/true then a value is emitted.

Comment: @Anne, please see my update.  I updated the original answer to reflect your comments, and I think the alternative answer I provide might be better than what you're looking for.

Comment: The second solution with race works perfectly and code is clean ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved by using the `buffer` operator that raises notification only after required interval elapsed in case the blocker stream does not cancel it in advance.

```
source$.pipe(
  buffer(source$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => timer(10).pipe(
      takeUntil(blocker$)
    ))
  ))
);
```

```js
const {timer} = rxjs;
const {buffer, exhaustMap, takeUntil} = rxjs.operators;
const {TestScheduler} = rxjs.testing;
const {expect} = chai;

const test = (testName, testFn) => {
  try {
    testFn();
    console.log(`Test PASS "${testName}"`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Test FAIL "${testName}"`, error.message);
  }
}

const createTestScheduler = () => new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  expect(actual).deep.equal(expected);
});

const createTestStream = (source$, blocker$) => {
  return source$.pipe(
    buffer(source$.pipe(
      exhaustMap(() => timer(10).pipe(
        takeUntil(blocker$)
      ))
    ))
  );
}

const testStream = ({ marbles, values}) => {
  const testScheduler = createTestScheduler();
  testScheduler.run((helpers) => {
    const { cold, hot, expectObservable } = helpers;
    const source$ = hot(marbles.source);
    const blocker$ = hot(marbles.blocker);
    const result$ = createTestStream(source$, blocker$)
    expectObservable(result$).toBe(marbles.result, values.result);
  });
}

test('should buffer changes with 10ms delay', () => {
  testStream({
    marbles: {
      source: ' ^-a-b 7ms ---c 9ms -----|   ',
      blocker: '^-   10ms --- 10ms -----|   ',
      result: ' --   10ms i-- 10ms j----(k|)',
    },
    values: {
      result: {
        i: ['a', 'b'],
        j: ['c'],
        k: [],
      },
    }
  });
});

test('should block buffer in progress and move values to next one', () => {
  testStream({
    marbles: {
      source: ' ^-a-b 7ms ---c 9ms -----|   ',
      blocker: '^-  8ms e---- 10ms -----|   ',
      result: ' --   10ms --- 10ms j----(k|)',
    },
    values: {
      result: {
        j: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        k: [],
      },
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.1.2/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```